# Code Signing and Gatekeeper Broken on 10.11

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I'm having trouble with Mac OS X Developer ID code signing for one of my application on Mac OS 10.11.

This problem affects 3 (yes I know) of my 4 Macs. I can build (from the command line) without any problems on my Mac Pro 2009 with Mac OS X 10.11 and Xcode 7 and my application will pass its gatekeeper test with flying colors:

```
% spctl --verbose=4 --assess --type execute MyApp.app
source=Developer ID
```

When I build with the same script on my other three Macs (MacBook Pro Retina, MacBook "one", Mac Pro 2014) with 10.11.1 and Xcode 7, I get:

```
rejected  
source=obsolete resource envelope
```

I upgraded the three machines that produce faulty builds with the GM on 10.11 and forgot to disable auto-updates to new beta versions, so they were auto-migrated to 10.11.1 beta 1 as soon as 10.11 final shipped. I thought this would go away once 10.11.1 shipped, so I tried this last night when it came out. Upgrading did not resolve the problem. So I upgraded Xcode to 7.1 and that didn't resolve anything either.

I looked up what the "obsolete resource envelope" means and it's said to be about using a version 1 signature, but running the tools (I think) shows that everything should be in order:

```
% /usr/bin/codesign -dv MyApp.app
Executable=/../MyApp.app
Identifier=my_bundle_id
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=5046 flags=0x0(none) hashes=245+3 location=embedded
Signature size=4236
Signed Time=Oct 21, 2015, 10:44:32 PM
Info.plist entries=32
TeamIdentifier=XXXXXXXX
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=536
Internal requirements count=1 size=216

% codesign --verify -vvv My.app
--prepared: MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/Current/.
--validated: My.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/Current/.
My.app: valid on disk
My.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

I read the "version=2" as "has version 2 signature", but I'm not sure about the "--prepared: ".. that this means it's valid or it's not signed?

I have had problems before where the Sparkle framework's symbolic link from A -> Current was replaced with a double directory entry (the contents of the symbolic link being replaced with a copy of the directory it points to). Is it possible that this causes the trouble?

I've listed the files to see whether there's a symbolic link going missing:

```
% ls -l My.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework
lrwxr-xr-x 1 frankreiff staff 24 Oct 21 22:44 Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
lrwxr-xr-x 1 frankreiff staff 26 Oct 21 22:44 Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
lrwxr-xr-x 1 frankreiff staff 24 Oct 21 22:44 Sparkle -> Versions/Current/Sparkle
drwxr-xr-x+ 4 frankreiff staff 136 Oct 21 22:44 Versions

% ls -l My.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions
total 8
drwxr-xr-x+ 6 frankreiff staff 204 Oct 21 22:44 A
lrwxr-xr-x 1 frankreiff staff 1 Oct 21 22:44 Current -> A
```

..but to my Unix-blind eyes everything seems in order.

Is anybody else experiencing code signing difficulties after upgrading to 10.11.1?

Any help would be very much appreciated..

Comment: For anybody else who is having trouble on El Capitan with code signing and Sparkle 1.5 beta Craig Hockenberry's blog entry provides the answer: http://furbo.org/2015/07/23/code-signing-in-el-capitan/